# How to find just first li elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have to create array of first li elements but i'm not sure how to do that.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="nav">
<ul>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2
        <ul>
            <li>Element 2.1</li>
            <li>Element 2.2</li>
            <li>Element 2.3</li>
            <li>Element 2.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Element 3</li>
    <li>Element 4
        <ul>
            <li>Element 4.1</li>
            <li>Element 4.2</li>
            <li>Element 4.3</li>
            <li>Element 4.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now i have to find first li elements of first ul - element 1, element 2, element 3, element 4.
So i want to use querySelectorAll but i don't know anything like nth-child in css or something

there is my JS querySelectorAll but i'm not sure how to find this

```
const allVisibleElements = document.querySelectorAll('');
```

Comment: Your exact need is to get Element 1, Element 2, Element 3, Element 4 alone so you can use like this https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/qBdmKBa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to target the `li` who are children of the `ul` who is the child of `.nav`, so you need to use the *child combinator* `>`:

```
const allVisibleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.nav > ul > li');
```

Comment: It is called the [child combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#child-combinators), not the "immediate child selector". Children are, by definition, immediate (as opposed to descendants which include children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc.)

Comment: right, updated. thanks (didn't recall the right term)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by referencing the direct child elements using [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>`:

```js
const allVisibleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.nav > ul > li');
allVisibleElements.forEach(e => e.setAttribute("style", "background-color:yellow"));
```

```css
ul,li { background-color: #fff }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2
      <ul>
        <li>Element 2.1</li>
        <li>Element 2.2</li>
        <li>Element 2.3</li>
        <li>Element 2.4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Element 3</li>
    <li>Element 4
      <ul>
        <li>Element 4.1</li>
        <li>Element 4.2</li>
        <li>Element 4.3</li>
        <li>Element 4.4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look at it from dev tools section of Chrome by right clicking to the element you want copy its Js path. Other answers are viable too but simplest way to do get JS path of an DOM element is this.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll` accepts CSS Selectors so you can write use `.nav > ul > li`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.nav>ul>li').forEach(e => console.log(e))
```

```html
<div class="nav">
<ul>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2
        <ul>
            <li>Element 2.1</li>
            <li>Element 2.2</li>
            <li>Element 2.3</li>
            <li>Element 2.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Element 3</li>
    <li>Element 4
        <ul>
            <li>Element 4.1</li>
            <li>Element 4.2</li>
            <li>Element 4.3</li>
            <li>Element 4.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
$('.nav > li:eq(0)').text();
```

Or

```
$('.nav > li:first').text();
```

Or

```
$( ".nav li:nth-child(1)" ).text();
```